# Camera children not showing up

Tags: javascript, three.js

Here I create my camera:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, width / height, 0.001, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 15, 0);
scene.add(camera);
```

I have this object I want to make the child of the camera

```
var handGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1, 32, 32 );
var handMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "#eac086"});
hand = new THREE.Mesh(handGeometry, handMaterial);
hand.position.set(1, 14, camera.position.z / 2);
```

I then add this object as a child of the camera

`camera.add(hand)`

However, the scene is empty, the child does not appear. I am using OrbitControls so I want my `hand` object to rotate *with* the camera as it is turned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a renderable object as a child of the camera, then you must add the camera to the scene graph:

```
scene.add( camera );
```

Then, set your child's position *relative* to the camera's position. Since the camera is always looking down its local negaitive-z axis, try

```
child.position.set( 0, 0, - 10 );
```

three.js r.73

Comment: Thanks! But I already tried that, it's included in the original post (unless I put it in the wrong place).

Comment: I'm not sure if you can still help with this, but after making this change the object I've attached to the camera has rotated 90 degrees on the y-axis.

Comment: `object.rotateY( - Math.PI / 2 );` ?